# Change separator in Bibliography only for year

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I am modifying a `.bst` file to be inline with my universities citation style. Most of the elements of the reference are required to be separated by a '.'. This is not for the case between the year and volume, which should be separated by a ';'.

I am editing a copy of `unsrtnat`.

I have already modified the `output.nonnull` function to output '.' instead of ',' as the separator.

```
FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ". " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
        { add.period$ write$
          newline$
          "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            { add.period$ " " * write$ }
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}
```

I am very new to TeX. I have been able to make some simple modification to the `.bst`, but I feel this is beyond my current skills. How would I do this?

Comment: For entries of type `@article`,  the `unsrtnat` bibliography style uses the following formatting and punctuation convention: "author. title. *journal*, volume(number):pages, year." Notice that `year` comes at the very end, rather than before `volume`. In short, it's not clear to me how you can achieve your desired format starting from the `unsrtnat` style. You may be better off using a different bibliography style as the starting point.

Comment: @Mico I started with the `unsrtnat.bst` file, and have somewhat modified it to make the references conform to my universities style, such that it has become `myunsrrtnat.bst`. I mentioned `unsrtnat.bst` as a point of reference. I have already moved the year to be next to the name of the journal.

Comment: @Mico I started with `unsrtnat` as it provided the references in the order in which the appeared in the document, something which `plainnat` did not, and which was based on advice provided in answers to other questions here.

Comment: Your formatting requirements (rather: your university's formatting requirements...) may be sufficiently unique as to make it desirable to start from scratch, specifically, by running the `makebst` utility that's part of the [custom-bib](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) package to create a bespoke bibliography style that contains all formatting requirements from the get-go. In contrast, if one attempts to modify an existing bibliography style, it's very easy to introduce bugs that are very hard to ferret out subsequently.

Comment: @Mico I've gone and done this; it seems like the most reasonable route. I seem to have some issues with author lists for in-text citations but hopefully I can work it out!